# download images with google customsearch api

Tags: python, api, google-custom-search

My question is probably trivial. But I tried to configure my customsearch engine to download the first 10 results of google image. Here is python script. It works except than my result a very far from the one of google image with the same parameter. Does someone can tell me what I miss?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys
from urllib import FancyURLopener
import urllib2
import simplejson
from apiclient.discovery import build


class MyOpener(FancyURLopener): 
    version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11'
myopener = MyOpener()

service = build("customsearch", "v1",
               developerKey="** my Key **")

res = service.cse().list(
    q='SearchTerm',
    cx='** my cx**',
    searchType='image',
    num=10,
    imgType='photo',
    fileType='jpg',
    imgSize="xxlarge"
).execute()

count=0
for item in res['items']:
  myopener.retrieve(item['link'],str(count))
  count=count+1
```

Comment: I may be completely wrong here but Google does a lot of customization while returning results. You may see different results based on what type of browser or OS used or even the location is considered too. I would suggest you to open two different browsers and seeing if you are getting the same types of results. Here is a TedTalk about this too http://www.ted.com/talks/eli_pariser_beware_online_filter_bubbles

Comment: Thank you. But here when i mean very different: I have got landscape vineyard when i ask for bottle of wine for example